# Get collision details from Rectangle.Intersects()

Tags: c#, xna, collision-detection, game-physics

I have a Breakout game in which, at some point, I detect the collision between the ball and the paddle with something like this:

```
// Ball class
rectangle.Intersects(paddle.Rectangle);
```

Is there any way I can get the exact coordinates of the collision, or any details about it, with the current `XNA API`?

I thought of doing some basic calculations, such as comparing the exact coordinates of each object on the moment of the collision. It would look something like this:

```
// Ball class
if((rectangle.X - paddle.Rectangle.X) < (paddle.Rectangle.Width / 2))
    // Collision happened on the left side
else
    // Collision happened on the right side
```

But I'm not sure this is the correct way to do it.

Do you guys have any tips on maybe an engine I might have to use to achieve that? Or even good coding practices using this method?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I've found at http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.xna.framework.rectangle.intersect.aspx

that there are two similar static methods (they differ on the way the value is returned) which as a result give You the intersection which also is a rectangle. This should be enough to do what You want.

Comment: Ok, with the returned Rectangle, how can I check the position of the paddle that got collided by the ball?

Comment: I don't understand what You're trying to get. The position of the paddle should be known regardless of collision. The position of impact area, where the ball touches the paddle is the resulting rectangle from those interct methods. If You wish to just know one point and the resulting rectangle is greater than that, You can just approximate by taking center of this rectangle.

Comment: I was trying to get to know if the ball hit the left or right side of the paddle. Finally I accomplished that with a simple calculation using the intersection rectangle. Thank you again!